# how make react-native-otp-inputs with hide input?

Tags: react-native, one-time-password

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1mxk.png)
`please help`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5tE8.png)

Comment: this input is not hidden.

Comment: use **secureTextEntry**